# How to keep android service always running?

Tags: android, sockets, service, background-process

It always seemed some sort of black magic the way other apps keeps their services always running, but mine gets killed by the system every time.

My app should keep a TCP socket open to the server and send/receive data when it becomes available, so it has to stay always on.

This is what I have tried so far:

1) Running the service in another process using this line (also with an additional line stopWithTask):

```
android:process="package.name.custom_process_name"
android:stopWithTask="false"
```

2) Restarting the service when these methods get called:

```
onTaskRemoved()
onDestroy()
```

3) Add `return START_STICKY` to `onStartCommand()` method

4) Check if the service is still running when these events happen:

```
android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

- Here I am stopping the socket connection to the server if the device does not have internet connection anymore and reopening it when it gets a connection.

Yet, my service always gets randomly killed (sometimes after few hours, sometimes after few days) by the system and doesn't restart automatically until I reopen the app.

How does other apps, say chat apps for example, keep their services available all the time?

**P.S.: Having a persistent notification would be the least of options.**

Comment: most of them are foreground services (`Service#startForeground`)

Comment: This implies showing a persistent notification, but look at Facebook, Whatsapp, Viber, Pushbullet. Those don't have a foreground notification and they are still running in background all the time.

Comment: why do you think they are "running in background all the time"?

Comment: Good question. I don't know, I'm assuming since I receive messages everytime. So it should either be always running, or *something* is waking the service up.

Comment: yes the second option is true: `something is waking the service up`, the app gets messages from the cloud, makes something and finishes

Comment: But what? How? When? Can you point me to some information about this?

Comment: push notifications, cloud messaging, gcm

Comment: your solution should be good. You wrote that: _my service always gets randomly killed by the system and doesn't restart automatically until I reopen the app._ The service is killed by the android system using its own logic and that is to be expected. What is unexpected is that your service doesn't restart automatically if you restart it in onDestroy. Can you share your implementation?

Comment: I finally had a chance to implement GCM as @pskink suggested and it seems to work fine. It has been few days since I did this and the service is still available when I need it. However, the approach that I used is probably wrong, using GCM only to ping device & start service (if needed) every 10 minutes.

Comment: so if you need an action to be performed  every x hours/days etc,  use AlarmManager then

Comment: I'll give that a try too then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override `onDestroy()` in your service, whenever your service destroys create Alarm using `AlarmManager`. When alarm trigger start your service again.

Second way is not recommended or proper way but create a separate service `AlwaysAliveService` which will do nothing but will remain available in android system.

Comment: Can't you just restart your service when onDestroy is called? What's the use of the `AlwaysAliveService` if it does nothing?

Comment: I was already restarting my service when `onDestroy()` happened, but didn't tried to use the AlarmManager. I will give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: Install ES File Explorer, and check they are using KeepAliveService. Second when system need some resources, system kills your service. So its not a good approach to start your service again.Take some time and restart it again. Which can be done using Alarm

Comment: What do you mean with _Install ES File Explorer, and check they are using KeepAliveService_? What I see is that ES File Explorer seems to be a foreground service. Did you mean that they are using the `AlwaysAliveService` trick? I didn't understand it yet, can you tell me something more? Thanks